# get the value from for loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to get the for loop value in php I have some names and I want to add '/'after each name and print the value outside the loop I want to get the $approver_name from for loop

```
foreach($co_practice as $co_practice_approver){
    // global $approver_name;
    if ($j >= 1) {
        $approver = users::where('id','=',$co_practice_approver)->first()->firstname;
        $approver_name = $approver_name . ' / ' . $approver;    
    } else {
        $approver_name = users::where('id','=',$co_practice_approver)->first()->firstname;
    }
}

 Hello {{$approver_name}}
```

now I got the output 'hello' without approver_name How to print the approver_name which I fetched in for loop

Comment: And the question is? Sure you remember [ask] and [mcve]?

Comment: Is this in a .blade file ? I think your syntax is wrong try remove the `{{}}` from `{{$approver_name}}` can you show the complete view?

Comment: ya It's a blade file.approver_name is printed when I fetch the approver value outside forloop

Comment: See the $approver_name is already overwritten and if your result returns null, you'll only see `Hello`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you fetch the `approver`'s `firstname` at once? Fetching data in loop will cause multiple queries in the database. Instead you could use [whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

**YourController.php**

```
public function yourMethod {
    // your other logic here...

    // this will query to get all users matching ids in $co_practice array
    // and pluck() will get the array of user's firstname 
    $firstNames = UserModel::whereIn('id', $co_practice)->pluck('firstname');

    // this will concatenate firstnames separated by '/'
    $approver_name = implode(' / ', $firstNames->all());

    // this will pass the $approver_name variable to view
    return view('your_blade_file', compact('approver_name'));
}
```

**your_blade_file.blade.php**

```
//now you can print the $approver_name
Hello {{ $approver_name }}
```